# Spring boot + JPA - repository findAll not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

##### Context

I am trying to build a simple Sprint boot REST service using spring-data-jpa with H2 database.

##### Problem Statement

All the controller methods that are using the service are <s>giving 404</s> giving 500. <s>On closer inspection, I found that the service injection in the controller is failing because the repository injection in the service is failing. Maybe it is an issue with component scanning.</s>. JPA findall is giving error

---

##### Entity

```java
package org.hiseb.hisebapi.model;

@Entity
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String value;

    @Column
    private String background;

    @Column
    private String font;

    // setters and getters
}
```

##### Repo

```java
package org.hiseb.hisebapi.repo;

@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends CrudRepository<Tag, Long> {
    Tag findByValue(String value);
}
```

##### Service

```java
package org.hiseb.hisebapi.service;

@Service
public class TagService {
    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    public List<Tag> read() {
        return (List<Tag>) this.tagRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

##### Controller

```java
package org.hiseb.hisebapi.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tags")
public class TagController {
    @Autowired
    private TagService tagService;

    @GetMapping("/all") // this is giving 404 error
    List<Tag> getAll() {
        return this.tagService.read();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/test") // this is working
    HttpStatus health() {
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }
}
```

##### StartUp

```java
package org.hiseb.hisebapi;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HisebApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HisebApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

###### Results

Hitting `localhost:8080/tags/all` gives -

###### Output

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2023-10-02T07:22:22.392+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/tags/all"
}
```

###### Console

```
2023-10-02 13:05:23.103 ERROR 11592 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Syntax error in SQL statement "select tag0_.id as id1_0_, tag0_.background as backgrou2_0_, tag0_.font as font3_0_, tag0_.[*]value as value4_0_ from tag tag0_"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select tag0_.id as id1_0_, tag0_.background as backgrou2_0_, tag0_.font as font3_0_, tag0_.value as value4_0_ from tag tag0_ [42001-214]
2023-10-02 13:05:23.149 ERROR 11592 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select tag0_.id as id1_0_, tag0_.background as backgrou2_0_, tag0_.font as font3_0_, tag0_.value as value4_0_ from tag tag0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select tag0_.id as id1_0_, tag0_.background as backgrou2_0_, tag0_.font as font3_0_, tag0_.[*]value as value4_0_ from tag tag0_"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select tag0_.id as id1_0_, tag0_.background as backgrou2_0_, tag0_.font as font3_0_, tag0_.value as value4_0_ from tag tag0_ [42001-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:261) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifier(Parser.java:5656) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermObjectDot(Parser.java:4838) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermWithIdentifier(Parser.java:5213) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:4901) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:3398) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:3385) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:3350) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:3132) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:3053) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectExpressions(Parser.java:2853) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2871) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2762) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2633) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2612) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2605) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2598) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2567) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:724) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2059) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:427) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hiseb.hisebapi.service.TagService.read(TagService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.hiseb.hisebapi.controller.TagController.getAll(TagController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:9.0.80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_333]
```

Hitting `localhost:8080/tags/test` gives 'OK'

###### Note

This repo is publicly available on GitHub - https://github.com/Bopsi/hiseb-api/tree/workitems/component-scan-on-entity-not-working

Comment: *"...the repository injection in the service is failing..."*. What's the error you see in the console on application startup? There should be some

Comment: I am not seeing any error in the console during start-up. Getting 404 in the API call. Updated the question with API results, please check.

Comment: Can you, please, enable [`debug` mode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.console-output) and see if there's any reason logged as to why the repository injection is failing? This is pretty weird, IF the injection is actually failing, the application should not start at all, because `@Autowired private TagRepository tagRepository;` is a **required** dependency in your service, so something is not right -- either you're missing something in your question or the injection is working ok and you just saw a red herring.

Comment: Also, an `Internal Server Error` is almost guaranteed to produce some error logs for you (unless you changed the logging level). Can you check that as well?

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null`. If an `@Autowired` field cannot be injected the application wouldn't even start. You also don't get a 404 you get a 500. So I doubt that this code is the actual code you are showing. One thing that is wrong about your controller is (and I suspect that there are more annotations on it) is that your methods aren't `public` which they should be. (As I suspect you have something like `@Secured` on them or something else that triggers AOP).

Comment: Updating my question again. Initially one of the packages was not under Main class package. Now it seems it an JPA error

Comment: Your exception clearly states the SQL is wrong, I suspect that `value` is a reserved keyword in SQL (or at least in H2).

Comment: I understand, but the query is created by JPA. May be there is some configuration error?

Comment: Set the `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers` property to `true` in your `application.properties`. `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` so that table names and column names are escaped in the query.

Comment: Finally found it. The error was there because the table was not getting created, also value is keyword I think
1) I had to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` in properties file, 2) value probably a keyword, changed it to label. 3) restart, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your repository and there are a couple of problems.

1. Your entity are named "Tag" but the tables are named "Tags"

You can specify the name of table in this way (or rename the table):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tags")
public class Tag {
```

2. Column value are reserved keyword in h2, change with value_ in script and add this on your entity :

```
@Column(name = "value_")
private String value;
```

3. Specify to Spring the db initialization file:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:data.sql
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

To access to h2 console go to "localhost:8080/h2-console" and check if table is created after startup.

One note: Your 'data.sql' really is 'schema.sql' because contains the script for schema/table creation :)

I can open pull request to you with fix :)

Answer (score 0):

> first of all, Injection Errors will stop the whole application so this is not one.

1. change your data.sql file name to schema.sql (cuz u r creating table not populating data) and change value to val to avoid reserved keyword errors

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tags` (
    id          INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `val`           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    background  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    font        VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

2. add both those lines to your application properties

`spring.sql.init.mode=always` to tell springboot to use schema.sql file and also data.sql if exists.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to prevent hibernate from trying to create schema from Entities.

3. in Tag class use the @Table and @Column annotations to match schema.sql file

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tags")
public class Tag {
    @Column(name = "val")
    private String value;
}
```

NOTE: If you are gettign column not found exception (go delete the old DB from C:/Work folder so that springboot creates the new one